# How to get current application in Django

Tags: django

I'm using the Django 1.3 alpha to create a project with two applications. I use 1.3 because of the class-based views. For these two applications I have a set of common base view-classes, that are inherited by the actual views in the applications. In the base class, is there a way to find out what application the view is "called" from? E.g. can I use the URL to get the "current" application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are inheriting from the generic list and detail views that django provides you could access `self.model` to gain access to the model that the view displays information about, otherwise you will probably have use [django's resolve()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve): `resolve(self.request.path)`.

You also could make your own `View` subclass that you call with a keyword of your choice:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.base import View
class MyView(View):
     app_name = None

# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from some_app.views import MyView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^myview/', MyView.as_view(app_name='app_name')),
)
```

Then you should be able to access it through `self.app_name`.

Comment: I didn't know the object returned from resolve() contained an app_name attribute. I changed my top project url-config file to use the app_name argument in the include calls including the application specific url-configs, then using resolve() to get the app_name from there. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this, but the app_name variable always returns `None`. Any advice?

Comment: How are you trying to access the variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to provide the app_name parameter in the URL definition. It works now, thanks :)