# How to get an app name using python in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

If you are in the view and want to retrieve the app name using Python ( the app name will be used for further logic ), how would you do it ?

Comment: `app_name = __package__.split('.')[0]`

Answer (score 33):

You could do:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

....

resolve(request.path).app_name
```

See [How to get current application in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256295/how-to-get-current-application-in-django) and [resolve()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve)

EDIT: You can now use [request.resolver_match.app_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match) which avoids resolving a second time and avoids an import. Do it this way:

```
request.resolver_match.app_name
```

Comment: *`resolve(request.path).app_name`* - in python3/django2 it's `from django.urls import resolve`. And both of your answers doesn't work.

Comment: @Henry I want to get the app_label instead of app_name. Is there any method to get app_label inside views.py.
Or some way to get the app_label using app_name ?

Comment: `resolver_match` isn't available in middleware

Answer (score 9):

```
__package__
```

or

```
__package__.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
```

should be the easiest way. Second converts `a.b.c` to `c`.

Comment: `__package__` returns 'project.app_name.folder'
`__package__.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]` returns 'folder'

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do it is get the current object or use self. see bellow

```
obj.__module__.split('.')
```

This will return a list with the object name split up by the '.'

Comment: Sorry, what is obj?

Answer (score 7):

You can get application name from model: `Book._meta.app_label`.

I've found in `django/contrib/admin/widgets.py`:

```
class RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper(forms.Widget):
    ...
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        from django.contrib.admin.views.main import IS_POPUP_VAR, TO_FIELD_VAR
        rel_opts = self.rel.model._meta
        info = (rel_opts.app_label, rel_opts.model_name)
        ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

so to sum up, If you're looking for the `app_name` of where your code is written, then use this:

```
app_name = __package__
```

However, if you need the `app_name` of where the object is being called (which might be in an app other than coding app), then use this:

```
import sys
from django.urls import resolve

app_name = sys.modules[resolve(request.path_info).func.__module__].__package__
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe this can help you..

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__) 
url = urlresolvers.reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (content_type.app_label, 
      content_type.model), args=(self.id,))
```

url will return you all adress and you can parse it for your app and model...

Answer (score 2):

This solution not very simple, but it works

```
import sys

sys.modules[resolve(request.path_info).func.__module__].__package__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#context-processors).
To create context processor for an app name do the following:

1. Say you have an app named myapp. Inside myapp directory create a context_processor.py
2. In context_processor.py define following method:

   ```
    def get_common_context(request):
        return {
            'app_name':'myapp'
        }
   ```
3. Add your context processor to TEMPLATES in settings.py

   ```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            ...
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    ...
                    'myapp.context_processor.get_common_context',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
   ```
4. Access app_name in your template.

   ```
    {{ app_name }}
   ```
5. Access app_name in your view using [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext)

Comment: This is unnecessary given that python offers this out of the box.

Comment: Could you share  how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the updated solution is `view.__module__`. This returns your `app_name` both from Django and Django Rest Framework.

My scenario was working with dynamically `module` or `app_name` from view call so that I can work with access permission check for that particular module.

Answer (score 0):

maybe my option would work for someone:

```py
### apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyApp(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app'

### models.py
from .apps import MyApp
name = MyApp.name
```