# How to construct a get_admin_url / get app_label and class name?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've got a model method `_get_admin_url` and want to construct the url dynamically.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

    def _get_admin_url(self):
        "Returns the admin url."
        # return '/admin/some_app/person/%d' %self.id
        return '/admin/%s/%s/%d/' %(..., ..., d)

    admin_url = property(_get_admin_url)
```

How can I get the values for app_label and class name? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Reversing admin URLs` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
c = Choice.objects.get(...)
change_url = urlresolvers.reverse('admin:polls_choice_change', args=(c.id,))
```

If you wish to refer the change_list page, you would do

```
urlresolvers.reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % (app_label, model_name))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But than I still need to hardcode 'polls' and 'choice'? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you would have to specify the app name and model name.

Comment: I found a way to set app name and model name. Thank you again for pointing me at reversing admin URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to set app_name and model_name with ContentType see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395481/991572

So I ended up doing this in `webapp/models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core import urlresolvers

class Base(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def _get_admin_url(self):
        "Returns the admin change view url."
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.__class__)
        view_name = "admin:%s_%s_change" % (content_type.app_label, content_type.model)
        url = urlresolvers.reverse(view_name, args=(self.id,)) 
        return url

    admin_url = property(_get_admin_url)            

class Book(Base):
    something = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Register Base and Book to the admin site, created some entries and in shell:

```
In [1]: from webapp.models import *

In [2]: Base.objects.get(pk=1).admin_url
Out[2]: '/admin/webapp/base/1/'

In [3]: Book.objects.get(pk=2).admin_url
Out[3]: '/admin/webapp/book/2/'
```