# How to get the name of current app within a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

What's the simplest way to access the name of the current app within template code?

Alternatively, what's the simplest way to define a template variable to hold the name of the current app?

(The goal here is to minimize the number of places I need to edit if I rename an app.)

Comment: What is current app anyway? As far as i know there is no CURRENT app. As app is not a set variable. You'll have to store or set it yourself by middleware or add to view as variable.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be good to define app name in settings file and access it through out project. In this way you will get rid of all sort of unprecedented bug.

Comment: this will tell you the app that the url of the current request belongs to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000205/how-to-get-an-app-name-using-python-in-django. Or maybe python introspection might be what your looking for: http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: @HenryFlorence: as it turns out, before I posted this question, I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out what `resolve` and `request` referred to in the SO answer you posted, all in vain.  Any clarification would be much appreciated.  (As this shows, I'm a django noob)

Comment: The request object is created for every http communication from the browser to your app. It includes all the data about the communication. The request is modified by middleware within your app, before being passed to your view functions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/ (there is a nice diagram further down the page). `Resolve()` is demonstrated in the answer below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a way to obtain an app name for a current request.
First, in your project's urls.py, considering your app is called `'main'`:

```
#urls.py
url(r'^', include('main.urls', app_name="main")),
```

Then, a context processsor:

```
#main/contexts.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
def appname(request):
    return {'appname': resolve(request.path).app_name}
```

Don't forget to enable it in your settings:

```
#settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"main.contexts.appname",)
```

You can use it in your template like any other variable: `{{ appname }}`.

Comment: Thanks!  Even though it's only 5 lines of code, it is about 5x as much code as I expected for this sort of thing.  I guess I'm surprised that Django does not consider this info useful enough to make it somehow readily available by default...

Comment: When you have more than one app, it is faster/simpler to have a single file *context.py* in your project, so that you respect the DRY principle.

Comment: Just to point out/emphasize, the `urls.py` is the top-level `urls.py` (and not, to follow the example, `main/urls.py`. (I missed this particular point for a bit.)

Comment: And to `#main.contexts.py` you could wrap the `resolve` look-up in a `try/except` for urls that don't have the `app_name` label, [an example here](https://gist.github.com/jheasly/4773f1a43decd3f3062b).

Comment: This still valid for Django 2.0.3?

Comment: For Django 1.11 you must add a **namespace** beside the app_name parameter, like **include('main.urls', app_name="mayapp", namespace="appns")**

Comment: Django 2.0 removed the `django.core.urlresolvers` so if you're using never Django version then `from django.urls import resolve`

Answer (score 28):

Since Django 1.5 there is a "resolver_match" attribute on the request object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

This contains the matched url configuration including "app_name", "namespace", etc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch

The only caveat is that it is not populated until *after* the first middleware passthrough, so is not available in process_request functions of middleware. However it is available in middleware process_view, views, and context processors. Also, seems like resolver_match is not populated in error handlers.

Example context processor to make available in all templates:

```
def resolver_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'app_name': request.resolver_match.app_name,
        'namespace': request.resolver_match.namespace,
        'url_name': request.resolver_match.url_name
    }
```

Comment: This worked great for me: `{{ request.resolver_match.app_name }}`. You just need request context processor enabled.