# How can I get the app name in Django 3+ within a template?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am looking for something like {{ appname }} to access the current app name of a site within a template.
Unfortunately, [answers for older versions of Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020911/how-to-get-the-name-of-current-app-within-a-template) seem to produce errors at various positions in the code.
Thank you!

Comment: This worked great for me: `{{ request.resolver_match.app_name }}`. You just need request context processor enabled.

Comment: @gulbazkhan: I think that is the `app_name` (namespace) of the `urls.py`, which can be different from the name of the app.

Comment: Thanks gulbaz khan, this works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

The answer, suggested by gulbaz khan: {{ request.resolver_match.app_name }}