# How can I get Django application name inside a decorator?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, decorator, django-2.0

I defined a decorator in Django as below:

```
from functools import wraps

def register_permission(my_input):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper():
            # ---------> I want app name here
            func()
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

then, I use it in some apps like :

```
@register_permission("some text")
def my_func():
   pass
```

Now,I want the app name of `my_func` , also I found [How to get an app name using python in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000205/how-to-get-an-app-name-using-python-in-django) question, but it can not help me.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your decorator will replace the class with a function. It that the desired behaviour?

Comment: Here you decorate a `func`tion, but in your example, you decorate a class?