# Django: resolve(request.path).app_name does not return app name

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to access the current app name from a view or template.

In other SO answers [How to get an app name using python in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000205/how-to-get-an-app-name-using-python-in-django/6000221#6000221) and [How to get current application in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256295/how-to-get-current-application-in-django/4256612#4256612) I found that `resolve(request.path).app_name` should return the current app name. But in my case it alwas returns "None".

I'm using Django 1.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that to work, you have to pass a `app_name` parameter when including your urls:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^manufacturers/', include('manufacturers.urls', app_name='manufacturers')),
)


#shell output
In [1]: resolve('/manufacturers/my_manufacturers/').app_name
Out[1]: 'manufacturers'
```

More info: [Defining URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a possibility to define this for all URLs inside an `urls.py` file?

Comment: @danilo-bargen you could define a 3-tuple variable in your application's `urls.py`, setting `app_name` in the second tuple item: `manufacturers_urls = (urlpatterns, 'manufacturers', None)`. You would then include this tuple in your project's `urls.py` `urlpatterns`. See [URL namespaces and included URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) for details of using this tuple approach.