# Django: Extend template by return value of template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, template-inheritance

In a template, I want to determine the parent template of a sub template via the return value of a template tag.

This is the template tag. It returns the app label (the package name) and appends the corresponding template name to be extended:

```
{% app_label request.path %}
```

Now what I want to do is this:

```
{% extends app_label %}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The `{% extends %}` tag needs to be the first template tag in a template ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance)):

> If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won't work, otherwise.

That means you can't have another template tag in front of it to construct a variable with the template's name.

However, you could call the template tag function (perhaps after some refactoring) in the view and add the variable to the template context. It's then a normal variable that you can use in the `{% extends ... %}`tag.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext):

```
def app_label_processor(request):
    return {
        'app_base_template': resolve(request.path).app_name
    }
```

Then I can use this:

```
{% extends app_base_template %}
```

All you need to do is

- adding your app urls as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7363786/1156004)
- adding your context processor to settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
- use `RequestContext` for rendering the template.